# Where is it valid?

Tags: inventor, us20120221930

In reference to the patent: [WO2012120036A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2012120036A1)

Is this patent valid worldwide and if not in which countries it is valid.

Comment: please answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate document is an international application and it is not "valid", it is merely an application.
This international application has spawned two "real" applications:

DE102011013224 - In Germany, abandoned on 2015/10/01

EP2683373 - In the EPO, still being actively examined:
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP12708816&lng=en&tab=doclist